# pine-script code for closing price on the following day

Tags: pine-script, trading

I understand how to get the closing price on the previous day - close[1] - to use in creating an indicator.

But, how do I get the closing on the following day?

I want to compare the closing price of the current day to the closing price one day before and one day after.

Comment: I can lend you mine time machine to get tomorrow quotes. will it help you?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to access to future values of a series using `[]`, it only allows you to access past values of a series. The function `security` can do that using `lookahead` but it is not straightforward.

Your best option is to interpret `close[1]` as the current price, `close[2]` as the price one-day before, and `close` as the price one day after.